# Open a file without knowing its type

Tags: android

I know that I can let user view their PDF file like that

```
   Intent intent;
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

   startActivity(intent);
```

But I was wondering, if I dont know the file type (could be an image, pdf, text ..etc). Is there away I can let the user open it (and android automatically detect the file type and show the list of possible programs)?

Thank you

Comment: there are some open source code u can use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
try
{
Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(aFile.getAbsolutePath());
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
startActivity(myIntent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
// TODO: handle exception
String data = e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: If it's a File, you can just use `file.extension`